# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DrawerLayout must be measured with MeasureSpec.EXACTLY.error while using MpAndroidChart api pie chart api

Tags: java, android, api, android-actionbar

Hi I am trying to implement a navigation  drawer on top of my pie chart but it keeps crashing however it seems to open the other activities just fine appreciated. I am using apptheme for the theme and MpAndroidChart api for the pie chart

### Java Code:

```
package com.example.gurpal.expenseapp;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.Chart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PieChartActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
Database db;

private static final int DURATION = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pie_chart);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    db = new Database(this);
    Cursor res= db.ViewData();


    PieChart expensesPieChart = (PieChart)findViewById(R.id.chart);

    ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> expensesCategories = new ArrayList<>();
    if(res.getCount() > 0)
    {
        int count = 0;
        res.moveToFirst();
        do
        {
            entries.add(new Entry((float)res.getDouble(2), count));
            expensesCategories.add(res.getString(1));
            count++;
        } while(res.moveToNext());
    }

    PieDataSet expensesDataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, null);

    PieData expensesData = new PieData(expensesCategories, expensesDataSet);

    expensesDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
    expensesPieChart.setDrawSliceText(false);
    expensesPieChart.setCenterText("Expenses");
    expensesPieChart.setCenterTextSize(30);
    expensesPieChart.setDescription("Money spent (in $CAD)");
    expensesDataSet.setValueTextSize(25);
    expensesPieChart.setDescriptionColor(Color.WHITE);
    expensesPieChart.setData(expensesData);
    Legend legend = expensesPieChart.getLegend();
    legend.setFormSize(15); // set the size of the legend forms/shapes
    legend.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.CIRCLE); // set what type of form/shape should be used
    legend.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
    legend.setTextSize(15);
    legend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    expensesPieChart.animateY(DURATION);
    expensesPieChart.invalidate();
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_menu_1:
            startActivity(new Intent(PieChartActivity.this, NavDrawer.class));
            break;

        case R.id.nav_menu_2:
            startActivity(new Intent(PieChartActivity.this, Expenses.class));
            break;

        case R.id.nav_menu_3:
            startActivity(new Intent(PieChartActivity.this, Income.class));
            break;

        case R.id.nav_menu_4:
            startActivity(new Intent(PieChartActivity.this, PieChartActivity.class));
            break;

        case R.id.nav_menu_5:
            Toast.makeText(PieChartActivity.this, "menu button test 5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }

    DrawerLayout dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    if(dl.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
        dl.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return false;
  }

}
```

### XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gurpal.expenseapp.PieChartActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navigationView">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Change the `<DrawerLayout>`'s `layout_width="wrap_content"` to `"match_parent"`.

Comment: Nice Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the piechart `tools:context`:

```
tools:context="com.example.gurpal.expenseapp.PieChartActivity"
```